# Need to make a javascript array to tell a story

Tags: javascript, events

I need to tell the story of the Three Little Pigs using an array as noted by my instructor. Any ideas of how to get started are greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Faith

Comment: Please post your code in the question and a live demo to reproduce the problem. We expect some code in questions that ask for code.

Comment: Here's a start: `['o', 'n', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'u', 'p', 'o', 'n', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e']`.

Comment: I think most poeple are willing to help you solve the problem.. if you showed that you've already tried and have questions that you can't answer..

Comment: and it might help to tell us what all that is supposed to mean...

Comment: @ArchyHolt **what???**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking strangers on the Internet to do your homework, with no evidence of an attempt to solve it yourself based on what you've been taught.

Answer (score 5):

```
var pigs = new Array("pig1", "pig2", "pig3");

function wolf_eat_pigs(pigs) {
    pigs = [];
    console.log("burb!");
}

wolf_eat_pigs(pigs);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/Sj3b5/6/

Comment: So the wolf ate all the pigs and the story ends...

Comment: Cool story. Almost exactly like how I remember it.

Comment: Redeclaring the pigs array will just leave them in the ether, waiting to be garbage collected.  I think the pigs should be popped one at a time.

Comment: Haha .. went for the short version.

Comment: Well, is ending up in the Garbage Collector better or worse than ending up in the Wolf's stomach...?

Comment: Sorry guys, you're right. Just fed the wolf.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This is my first project that I'm building. I know the fundamentals, but it's time that I now try to build something.

Comment: And yes, it looks like the wolf had a triple delight.

Comment: Looking at the "[silly symphony](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Olo923T2HQ4)" version, the house of two pigs get destroyed. You could make three arrays holding one pig and one type of house. Then you can have the wolf look at the house of each array. If it is not made of stone, destroys the house and add that pig to the array with the stone house.